# Не работает фильтр в SearchView

Tags: android-search-view

Ребята не могу разобраться как сделать фильтр при вводе данных в Searchview. Не хочет фильтровать введенные данные.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    final List<String> suggestions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mycity));

    final CursorAdapter suggestionAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            null,
            new String[]{SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);

    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionAdapter);

    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            searchView.setQuery(suggestions.get(position), true);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false; 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            String[] columns = { BaseColumns._ID,
                    SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,

            };
            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);
            for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); i++) {
                String[] tmp = {Integer.toString(i),suggestions.get(i),suggestions.get(i)};
                cursor.addRow(tmp);
            }
            suggestionAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Куда копать, что смотреть, чего не хватает.

Comment: для начала уберите все из метода `onCreateOptionsMenu`. тут только меню должно создаваться. глядишь и решение само придумаешь, когда код будет структурным

Comment: Мне кажеться, одно другому не помеха. Может оно и не совсем правильно, но вопрос немного был по другому.

Comment: Ребята помогите разобраться, почему не выбирается  нужное слово при вводе. Я перерил весь интернет, конструкция абсолютно рабочая, возможно я просто где-то упустил какую то мелочь.